# Ctrl + Click on any Control on form run different function

Tags: wpf, vb.net

How can this be achieved:

I want to be able to run specific function only by CTRL + left click on any form element, just left clicking that element should retain original handler and function.

Equivalent to:

```
If My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown Then
            ...
        Else
            ...
        End If
```

but in my case i want to send element.Name to another function.

Is there a way to implement it on whole form (wpf form) so that if I ctrl+click any control on form i get a messagebox showing me x:name of that control

Comment: `Dim Name As String = DirectCast(sender, FrameworkElement).Name`?

Comment: If you say "window", which is the WPF term, rather than "form", which is the WinForns term, then it is less likely that people will make the mistake of assuming that it's WinForms. Not guaranteed, but less likely.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      If Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.Control Then
         MessageBox.Show("Do Ctrl-Click logic")
      Else
         MessageBox.Show("Do Click logic")
      End If
   End Sub
```

Comment: The question relates to WPF, not WinForms.